# Generating liquibase changelog file only for data

Tags: database, oracle, cmd, liquibase, changelog

I want to generate a liquibase changelog file only for the data of an oracle database. This is the comamand I use in cmd:

```
.\liquibase `
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver `
--classpath=C:/svn_planio/TST/resources/lib/ojdbc7.jar `
--changeLogFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\sdk\workspace\changelog\com\example\CL_Data.xml" `
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ferdec" `
--username=username `
--password=password `
--diffTypes="data" `
generateChangeLog
```

But it gives me this error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: oracle.xdb.XMLType

It works fine when I remove the `--diffTypes="data"` but then liquibase generates a usual changelog file but I need one only with data from the database.

Comment: Liquibase is really mainly intended for use in managing the structure (schema) of a database, and not the contents (data) that is stored in a database.

Comment: @SteveDonie I have successfully managed the structure of the database with liquibase but now I need to manage the data too. Do you know other ways to manage the contents of the database that maybe go well with liquibase?

Comment: That is a topic that is too big to get into in comments, and depends a lot on the kind of data you need to manage. Is it 'transactional' data, or is it more like 'constant' data? Is this for testing/development use, or are you doing things in a production environment? The answers to those may overlap also - liquibase might be OK for managing 'constant' data that is the same across dev/test/prod, but not at all for transactional data that is not the same in different enviroments. The RedGate tool suite might be a good place to look. You'd have to describe the underlying problem being solved.